Why I need to pass Secure Random when I am loading the key from PKCS8 format
I am using Ring lib in Rust to generate ECDSA_P256 and I am passing SystemRandom, and I am getting PKCS8 key pair format. Until this point, there is no issue.
let rng = SystemRandom::new();
let pkcs8_bytes = signature::EcdsaKeyPair::generate_pkcs8(&signature::ECDSA_P256_SHA256_ASN1_SIGNING, &rng)
.map_err(|e| Error::KeyGenerationFailed(e.to_string()))?;

The issue for me is when I am loading the key pair from PKCS8 format, it's asking again to pass Secure Random, e.g:
let rng = SystemRandom::new();
let key_pair = signature::EcdsaKeyPair::from_pkcs8(
      &signature::ECDSA_P256_SHA256_ASN1_SIGNING,
      pkcs8_bytes.as_ref(),
      &rng,
).map_err(|e| Error::KeyGenerationFailed(e.to_string()))?;

Why I need to pass new SystemRandom If I am only reloading the key pair from bytes?
I know that the nonce should be always the same for the same Kaypair, but it should be different for each Sign operation, or I am wrong?

First I thought that this was to validate the public key for the key pair by performing a sign/verify, but this is not the case.
The reason why the RNG is used is to protect against faulty RNG's during the signing operation. If an adversary knows about these states then having two related signatures (r, s) allow an attacker to calculate the private key used. This can be done by making sure that there doesn't exist an equation to derive one r value from another.
So this Rust implementation of ECDSA protects against this by making sure that the RNG relies on the combination of the random nonce-key, the hash over the message as well as the random number generator. It's a weird mix of deterministic ECDSA and a secret to mix with the RNG used. This is a way to make sure that the RNG doesn't error and create two realated r values.
This is all implementation specific, which is why you probably won't find the same requirement of a secure RNG to be present in other libraries.

Call to new function in from_pkcs8 is here:
https://docs.rs/ring/latest/src/ring/ec/suite_b/ecdsa/signing.rs.html#118
which exclusively uses it for a call to NonceRandomKey::new here:
https://docs.rs/ring/latest/src/ring/ec/suite_b/ecdsa/signing.rs.html#161
which is picked up during signing here to create a NonceRandom which is an implementation of an RNG:
https://docs.rs/ring/latest/src/ring/ec/suite_b/ecdsa/signing.rs.html#182
which contains the important comment:

Generates an ECDSA nonce in a way that attempts to protect against a faulty SecureRandom.

which finally gets used as an RNG during signing in sign_digest, call here:
https://docs.rs/ring/latest/src/ring/ec/suite_b/ecdsa/signing.rs.html#188

You must pass a secure RNG to the class because it generates unique nonces for each signature, requiring access to a cryptographically secure random source.

If it was apparent why an ECDSA key pair would require a nonce then this answer could have had some merit, even though it doesn't have much explanatory power. But since that is not apparent at all it fails on every front in my opinion. Oh, and I did post an (incorrect) answer, not the org. author.

Ohhhh.... "Deleted by the post author..."  I gotcha

No, i mean by the amount of unfriendly venom in your comment i assumed it was a frustrated original post author - the original poster who created the question. I imagined he was having a frustrating head-banging time, was too impaitient for a gentle nudge. Your answer goes into great, great, detail. Which boils down to *"Why do i have to pass a secure RNG?"  Function: "Cause I said so"

What answer? No other function to import PKCS#8 encoded keys in any API require a RNG. And you simply say: well, because any signature requires a RNG, while the API clearly shows you need to provide an RNG for the signature generation function as well. Your post explains nothing, and they you start complaining about my answer because it is too detailed?

I wasn't complaining about your answer being too detail. Your answer is exactly what i would have written; but why should i re-write that when you already did all the good hard work. In fact, i was directing the original poster to  your answer. Which brings up the important question: why are you so angry?
